# How simplify this sum?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I need help to simplify this sum :

$$\sum_{i=0}^{x-1}\left(1-\dfrac{1}{2^i}\right)^{m-1}$$

Is it possible to simplify it ?

Thank you.

Comment: $x , m$ are integers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $x,m\in\mathbb{N}\setminus\{0\}$, let we replace $x-1$ with $n$ and $m-1$ with $s$. Then:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(1-\frac{1}{2^i}\right)^s = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{k=0}^{s}\binom{s}{k}\frac{(-1)^k}{2^{ik}}=\sum_{k=0}^{s}\binom{s}{k}(-1)^k\frac{1-2^{-kn}}{2^k-1}$$
but I do not see any particular reason for considering the last sum "prettier" than the first one.

Comment: If $x$ is very large then the second form is better because you reduced a very large summation to finite summation in $s$, but if $n$ is fixed and $m$ is very large the first summation is better